# "RTNETLINK answers: File exists" after upgrading to Debian 7

Tags: networking, debian-wheezy

I upgraded my system from Debian 6 to Debian 7.3 yesterday.

After rebooting, I chose the new kernel `linux-image-3.2.0-4-amd64` and the network became unavailable.

I tried `sudo service networking restart` and got the following errors:

```
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Failed to bring up eth0.
```

I only setup for eth0. Here's my `/etc/network/interfaces`.:

```
auto lo eth0
iface lo inet loopback

iface eth0 inet static
    address x.x.x.x
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway x.x.x.x
```

and the routing table is empty `sudo route -n`:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
```

However, the old kernel `2.6.32-5-amd64 x86_64` still works.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I finally found the reason. The firmware of the NIB is missing. Just added `contrib` and `non-free` branch in `/etc/apt/sources.list` then update again. After rebooting, the network is available.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the new kernal can see the interface with :

```
ifconfig -a
```

if the interface is listed, check it's name,

then assign an ip manually, assuming the name is eth0

```
ifconfig eth0 IP_ADDRESS netmask NET_MASK
```

example:
    ifconfig eth0 192.168.1.1 netmask 255.255.255.0

add default gw, assuming the gateway is 192.168.1.254

```
route add default gw 192.168.1.254
```

This is just a temp solution.

Comment: In new kernel, the ip and netmask were set correctly on system startup. If I tried to assign an IP manually, it gives the error `SIOCSIFFLAGS: No such file or directory`. Adding gateway gives the error `SIOCADDRT: no such process`.